# Hot/Neutral reversed at receptacles after AFCI breaker was installed, can AFCI still work correctly?

Tags: receptacle, afci

Starting condition:
I have 3 outlets in a room and 2 of them have Hot and Neutral reversed.

Change:
The electrician came in an installed AFCI breakers
At my request, they also changed the outlets to white ones so that would match the trim

New condition:
Now all the outlets in that room has Hot/Neutral reversed.

My question is this: I can reverse the wiring in the outlets to fix the outlets.  But if the Hot and Neutral are reversed at the AFCI, will the AFCI still work correctly?

Comment: Having hot and neutral reversed is utterly unacceptable whether an AFCI receptacle would work or not. Call that electrician back or get a new one out. How do you know the hot and neutral are reversed?

Comment: I will call the electrician. FYI I'm using AFCI breakers not receptacles.

Comment: Are the 3 receptacles in this room all on the same circuit? How many breakers were changed to AFCI?

Comment: Can you post photos of the load-side wiring on the AFCI breaker and the wiring at each receptacle?

Comment: After the electricians come out and fix this, I hope the querant will report the details of what caused this. It's hard to imagine how. Say the electrician (correctly) installed two new breakers (AFCIs) and noticed that one of the old breakers was wired with an unusual color of wire. Wouldn't he have thought to check the receptacles that were on the circuit?

Comment: Beware your detection method on the hot/neutral reversal. If you're plugging in some rinkydink made-in-China tool you got off the endcap at Home Depot, you may not be getting reliable data.

Comment: I have seen outlets that are daisy chained cross wired by DIY folks that did not know what they were doing. If all the electrician did was replace breakers, outlets  and the wire color was correct there the electrician did nothing wrong. If the wire colors are not correct from this work the electrician needs to be reported.