# ELCB tripping is multiple circuits at same time

Tags: wiring

A neutral a earth fault on a 1 floor of the house is causing ELCB of the other floor to trip. These two RCDs are fed by the two different cables outgoing from the main distribution board .

Trying to find the reasons the fault is not contained within the faulty distribution board. Have checked main earthing as well.

Comment: Are there any rogue bonds between earth and ground? Sometimes inexperienced DIY-ers will bond neutral to earth in an outlet box.

Comment: ground floor main DB has a earthing point solidly grounded. Utility service main is a 4 core cable. Earth wires are carried separately to each floor from the main DB

Answer (score 2):

Anytime a *single* fault trips *two* ground fault detectors, the cause is that the circuits are crossed.

Either the neutrals have been tied together somewhere; the hots have been tied together somewhere; or a particular load is drawing hot from one circuit and returning neutral to the other circuit.  This can and should trip both ground-fault detectors.

It should be completely OK to share or cross grounds.   Of course a neutral-ground fault will also cause a ground-fault detector trip.

I go into more detail in [my answer over here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/106368/47125).  Though the questions seem quite different, they are the same core issue.